# Regular expression to remove the last column from a pipe delimited file

Tags: regex, vim

I've got a file with 1000's of entries and 131 columns, the columns are pipe delimited. There is no pipe at the end so format is something like.

2010-10-04|Security|AMEND|20162214| ... lots more columns ... |Bloomberg

How can I remove the last column of the file say in Vim ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tou need

```
%s/|[^|]*$//
```

Note I am using `[^|]*` to allow for an empty column.

Answer (score 4):

This regular expression will catch the last column: `\|[^|]+$`

Comment: I'm getting pattern not found when I try that one.

Comment: Make sure you've escaped it appropriately for your language

Comment: You need `|`  not `\|` in vim

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
:%s/.*\zs|.*//
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `cut`, or `awk` at a push