# regex to remove all text in last column of pipe-delimited ragged flat file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a ragged .pip, pipe-delimited, quote-qualified flat file with 3 columns.  The end-of-record delimiter is carriage-return line-feed ({CR}{LF}).  An example file is:

```
x|stuff|zz {CR}{LF}
ab|"some|thing"|"els|e" {CR}{LF}
"wh|at"|text|b {CR}{LF}
```

I need to remove the text in the last (3rd) column, including its column delimiter.  So, I want the above example file to appear as:

```
x|stuff {CR}{LF}
ab|"some|thing" {CR}{LF}
"wh|at"|text {CR}{LF}
```

I want to use a regex find-replace in Notepad++.  What should my regex (find) be?  I know there is a similar post for this ([Regular expression to remove the last column from a pipe delimited file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874955/regular-expression-to-remove-the-last-column-from-a-pipe-delimited-file)), but it doesn't seem to work for my situation.

Comment: Why don't you record a macro i.e., Start recording > Find Pipe > Skip to second Pip > Use right arrow to remove selection from the second pipe and move to next letter > do shift + end to select the text > Delete > Enter > STOP MACRO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search pattern can be constructed by a literal pipe (must be escaped), followed by zero or more non-pipe chars (greedy) and anchored at end of line. But I see that some of the fields may contain quoted values with pipes. So you would need to handle those in a separate match. Try this:

```
\|("[^"]*"|[^|]*)$
```

I just tested this pattern on your example data set and confirmed it works. Do you have any quoted values that have quote characters that need to be escaped? If so, how are they escaped? With a leading quote? With a backslash? Perhaps it might be better to use a CSV parser instead of a regex if you do have any quoted data in the last column with literal quotes inside.

Comment: I don't think I will ever have quoted values that will have quote characters inside of them, even though it may be possible.  I will keep that in mind as I use this on the files.